# Angular 2 Data Mocking by Configuration like Ember Mirage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying to figure out how to mock data by configuration like I would in Ember Mirage but in Angular 2.  I know I can build something from scratch using DI and MockBackend to intercept calls in HTTP and return data.  Does Angular 2 or Angular 2 CLI have something built in I am missing, or a standard package that does this?

Comment: With 13K rep you should know by now that asking for recommendations is off-topic.

Comment: @j08691 I am actually curious to know the answer to this/waiting for an answer to this...Please don't flag.

Comment: @FrankTudor - You may be curious, however that doesn't make it any less off-topic for SO.

Comment: I changed the text so this is a general question.

Comment: The "AngularJS" tag's description: Use for questions about AngularJS (1.x), the open-source JavaScript framework. Do NOT use this tag for Angular 2 or later versions; instead, use the [angular] tag. Can you please update to remove that tag?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar and ran across this: http://devlucky.github.io/kakapo-js

Comment: Not sure why this received a down vote, according to their documentation: "Kakapo its a full featured http mocking library, he allows you to entirely replicate your backend logic in simple and declarative way directly in the browser. This way you can easily prototype and develop the whole Application without backend and just deactivate Kakapo when you go production. In order to achieve that Kakapo gives you a set of utilities like Routing, Database, Response, Request and so on…".  Sounds like a possible solution for looking for a "Mirage like" service outside of Ember.

Comment: How does this plug into the Angular 2 CLI the way that Mirage does into the Ember CLI?